# Docusign eSignature REST API authentication

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign in my Web application. The website workflow will be as follows:

1. Users visit my website and log in.
2. Users will be given the option to choose Docusign Templates.
3. After selection, users need to sign that document.
4. After a successful signing, the signed document is sent to some authority.

My problem is how can I link my users to Docusign to sign. Does every user needs to have an account for embedded signing?? I need some help in understanding the flow of authentication and signing in DocuSign REST API. I have gone through the documentation but didn't understand properly. When I try to use the auth grant GitHub code to understand the flow. After logging in, it throws a null pointer exception. Please, someone, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find [code example in different languages](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-use-template) to do what you're asking (sign from a template). You will want to use embedded signing so that the user sign as part of the app and not remote signing (via email). 
As for your authentication question, no, signers never need to be part of the account. The sender can be a single user that is "sending" envelopes that are embedded in the app. So while there's no sending technically, you can think of it this way. 
Hope this makes sense, please ask additional questions if not clear

recipientID is a GUID uniquely used to identify a recipient in DocuSign. When you create an envelope, each recipient should have one.

"and If the same name+email combination comes again, will it get the same signature or generate a new one?" It will remember it if they have an account.

Comment: Then how can the signatures be unique to each user??. And for return users how can I get there previously used signatures??

Comment: they are unique based on their name+email combination, but you also put what we call RecipientID which is a unique GUID

Comment: return users - you can have your own db to remember who is who etc. but if you want the users to use DocuSign to find past signatures - they have to have an account

Comment: Can we let them create their own account in docusign from my web application?? and If the same name+email combination comes again, will it get the same signature or generate a new one?? And can you elaborate more on RecipientID

Comment: recipientID is a GUID uniquely used to identify a recipient in DocuSign. When you create an envelope, each recipient should have one.

Comment: you can let them create their own account from your app, yes

Comment: "and If the same name+email combination comes again, will it get the same signature or generate a new one?"
It will remember it if they have an account

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please add this information in the answer and last question, can you share any link on how to let users create DocuSign account in my web application.

Comment: if you are a partner of DocuSign - you can use this one https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/Accounts/create
To become a partner, you may need to check https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner

Comment: if you are not - you can use the following URL https://account.docusign.com/sign-up?response_type=code&scope=all&client_id=